# is it possible to make my exe az child process in other parent process

Tags: c++, vb.net

Is it possible to make my Project as a child process in other parent process?

Comment: Of course it's possible, so yes.

Comment: do you have the plan.. if you can!!

Comment: _" if you can!!"_ I well can, no need to get aggressive dude!

Comment: I did not mean that
Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Is it possible to make my Project as a child process in other parent process?"*

Yes it is possible to do so. Look into the POSIX functions

- [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) how to create a child process
- [`exec()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) and related how to replace the child process code with another executable running it.